# Is there a way to select every column from one column to another with brackets in R?

Tags: r

I know in `subset()` you can pull every column starting with one and ending with another pretty easily.

```
df <- as.data.frame(state.x77)
subset(df, Frost > 30, select=Illiteracy:Murder)
```

I know with brackets you can do something like `df[df$Frost > 30, 3:5]`

Is there a way to recreate the subset statement with brackets that uses the column names?

Comment: `dplyr select` should do. Combine it with `filter` or `filter_at`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find

```
df <- state.x77
df[df[, "Frost"] > 150, c("Illiteracy", "Life Exp", "Murder")]
```

produces

```
              Illiteracy Life Exp Murder
Alaska               1.5    69.31   11.3
Colorado             0.7    72.06    6.8
Maine                0.7    70.39    2.7
Minnesota            0.6    72.96    2.3
Montana              0.6    70.56    5.0
Nevada               0.5    69.03   11.5
New Hampshire        0.7    71.23    3.3
North Dakota         0.8    72.78    1.4
South Dakota         0.5    72.08    1.7
Vermont              0.6    71.64    5.5
Wyoming              0.6    70.29    6.9
```

Incidentally, `state.x77` is a matrix, not a dataframe.  As a matrix you could use

```
df <- state.x77
df[df[, "Frost"] > 150, which(colnames(df)=="Illiteracy"):which(colnames(df)=="Murder")]
```

or as a dataframe

```
df <- as.data.frame(state.x77)
df[df[, "Frost"] > 150, which(names(df) == "Illiteracy"):which(names(df) == "Murder")]
```

to produce the same result, and you could write a function to make this prettier

Comment: Is there a `columna` to `columnb` equivalent with brackets? I'm thinking about dataframes with many, many columns.

Comment: @Cauder - I have added an example of a range of columns

Answer (score -1):

Another approach with dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
df = as.data.frame(state.x77)
df %>% filter(Frost > 30) %>% select(Illiteracy:Murder) %>% head()

  Illiteracy Life Exp Murder
1        1.5    69.31   11.3
2        1.9    70.66   10.1
3        0.7    72.06    6.8
4        1.1    72.48    3.1
5        0.9    70.06    6.2
6        2.0    68.54   13.9
```